# Disable device idle detection in wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How I can disable Device Idle detection. So my app keep running and its not goes to idle mode or in lock screen.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the `ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` property to `disabled`?

Even so, the OS could still force your app to idle if (for instance) the battery gets too low.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

/* Disable the application idle detection by setting the UserIdleDetectionMode property of the application's PhoneApplicationService object to Disabled. Caution:- Use this under debug mode only. Application that disables user idle detection will continue to run and consume battery power when the user is not using the phone. */

PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

//To run the application under lock screen use the line below

PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

Also note ApplicationIdleDetectionMode cannot be enabled after it has been disabled. ApplicationIdleDetectionMode cannot be set until the application’s PhoneApplicationFrame object has been initialized.

Comment: Also please clarify with the Certification rules before submitting the app on marketplace